# Handling empty lists in PHP SOAP

Tags: php, soap

Initially if there was one item in the list it would return an object rather than an array of one object. I fixed that using:

https://eirikhoem.wordpress.com/2008/03/13/array-problems-with-soap-and-php-updated/

```
$x = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
```

But I'm having problems when there is no items in the list.

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
$occulist = $result->GetWebOccurrencesResult->OccuList;
if (!empty((array)($occulist))) {
    foreach($occulist->TOccu as $occurrence) {
        echo $occurrence->Prog_Name . ' running from ' . $occurrence->StartDate . ' to ' . $occurrence->EndDate . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Originally it was

```
foreach($result->GetWebOccurrencesResult->OccuList->TOccu as $occurrence) {
```

Comment: And what are these problems you speak of..? What is it doing that you don't want it to do? What is it NOT doing that you want it to do?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it like how SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS lets you keep on using foreach when there is one item. At the moment I'm casting the object as an array to check if it is empty.

Comment: [This](http://shwup.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/arrays-in-soap.html) might be what you're looking for

Comment: Yes 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS is what I mentioned... I suspect that if the array was empty in that link it would also not work.

Comment: I meant the function at the bottom to create your array, but what does `var_dump(!empty((array)($occulist)));` return?

Comment: It returns bool(false) if there are no "occurrences" otherwise it returns bool(true)

Comment: Why don't you just throw an `} else { echo 'the list is empty..'; }` on the end of that if you have there...?

Comment: If it was an empty array for the foreach input it would automatically skip the foreach. That's what I was looking for... avoiding the if statement altogether.

Comment: You're going to have to do it that way, how else would you evaluate against it? You could try a `do-while` but that won't give you an option to print something if the array is empty as it doesn't have an "else" option that you could possibly attach around it

Comment: If the array is empty I don't want it to do anything so I don't need an else statement. At the moment what I do is something like $dropdown = array() near the start then in the foreach I add items to it ($dropdown[] = )

Comment: What's `var_dump($result->GetWebOccurrencesResult->OccuList)` when it's empty?

Comment: By memory it was something like Object {} (an empty object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my server with Windows and PHP 5.4.23 this:

```
if (!empty((array)($occulist))) {
```

gives the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(array)' (array) (T_ARRAY_CAST)
```

I fixed it using:

```
if (get_object_vars($occulist)) {
```

I think that is a more elegant alternative to the original...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve here, so if you can clarify in the comments, that'd be great.

What I'm taking from your question is that you want to handle when the array is empty, but want a clean method to do so? The loop you have there would do what you require, but here is another alternative:

```
do {
    foreach($occulist->TOccu as $occurrence) {
        echo $occurrence->Prog_Name . ' running from ' . $occurrence->StartDate . ' to ' . $occurrence->EndDate . '<br/>';
    }
} while(empty((array)($occulist)) !== FALSE);
```

So you're looping through the foreach while the `$occulist` array isn't empty.
You could even do:

```
while((array)$occulist !== FALSE) {
    foreach(....) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The original code was:
foreach($result->GetWebOccurrencesResult->OccuList->TOccu as $occurrence) {

ideally the first part of the foreach would evaluate to an empty array if the list is empty and then it would skip the foreach statement.

Comment: Then change it to that...?

Comment: It doesn't handle empty lists like I would like... also since I created a variable called $occulist it becomes shorter to change it to foreach($occulist->TOccu as $occurrence) {

Comment: @LukeWenke Life isn't easy buddy, sometimes you have to add a few more characters than you want to, that's the nature of this job. Your question is actually off-topic, since you want to format your code...So yeah.

Comment: ok thanks. I had hoped there was another SOAP option... oh well.